# Escaping the > character

Tags: perl, escaping, character

I have a text  file whose content is 
`<rapidwizloc oa_var="s_rapidwizloc">C:\temp</rapidwizloc>`

I want the value `C:\temp` to be replaced by a different value which gets defined from a variable

Also the perl oneliner will be called from batch file (windows .cmd)

```
set CMDDIR=C:temp1
set str1=C:temp
echo %CMDDIR%
echo %str1%
```

`perl -pi.bak -e "s/s_rapidwizloc\"\>%str1%/s_rapidwizloc\"\>%CMDDIR%/g" a.txt`

when running the .cmd I am getting

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

To escape the `>` character in Windows batch files, use the circumflex, thus `^>`.